# Enable an HTML form text box based on the value of a drop down menu in the same form?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to HTML and I'm aware that this question has been asked several times on here, but I've tried all the various solutions and none have worked for me.  I'm trying to activate a field (which defaults to disabled) when one of two values is selected from a drop down menu. This is the JavaScript function I have written to accomplish the task.

```
function changeTextBox() {
    comp = document.getElementById('comparator');
    if(comp.value=='equalto'||comp.value=='notequalto')
        document.getElementById('localevalue').disable=false;
    else
        document.getElementById('localevalue').disable=true;    
}
```

This is the drop down menu

```
<label style="font-size:16px" for="comparator">Comparator:</label>
<select id="comparator" name="comparator" onChange="changeTextBox();">
    <option value="lessthan">Less Than</option>
    <option value="lessthanequalto">Less Than or Equal To</option>
    <option value="greaterthan">Greater Than</option>
    <option value="greaterthanequalto">Greater Than or Equal To</option>
    <option value="equalto">Equal To</option>
    <option value="notequalto">Not Equal To</option>
    <option value="exists">Exists</option>
</select>
```

And this is the field that needs to be activated when 'Equal To' or 'Not Equal To' are selected from the drop down menu.

```
<label style="font-size:16px" for="value">Value:</label>
<input type="number" id="value" disabled/>
```

But when I select one of the fields, the box remains deactivated.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: disabled, not  disable

Comment: Please put FIXED in your title so others know that the problem is resolved.

Comment: @MathSquared11235 You're suggesting a Very Bad Thing for an SO user to do. The way questions are marked as resolved is by an accepted answer either on the one the OP gave themselves, or other answers provided by the community

Comment: @Bojangles Good point, but then how is J. Random Hacker supposed to know that this question was answered by a comment?

Comment: The OP should post an answer of their own stating the solution they found (however simple) and mark it as accepted

Comment: And if 'fixed' (or any variations thereof) *ever* go into a title, it will be removed. Quickly. And with a varying degree of prejudice, the precise degree of which is logarithmically proportional to the use of  upper-case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I should have been using .disabled, not .disable in my JS function.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
function changeTextBox() {
    var comp = document.getElementById('comparator');
    if(comp.value=='equalto'||comp.value=='notequalto')
        document.getElementById('value').disabled=false;
    else
        document.getElementById('value').disabled=true;    
}
```

Edit: sorry, the page was loaded and I haven't notice dandavis comment. Besides that, in my reply I've changed the document.getElementById('localevalue') to document.getElementById('value')

Comment: Sorry dandavis, it wasn't my intention. Besides, I hasn't enough reputation to post comments, so a reply was the only way.

Comment: i'm just bustin your balls a little bit, no big whoop.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Stack Overflow</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
function changeTextBox()
{
         var val=$('#comparator').val();

          alert(val);
      if(val==='equalto' || val==='notequalto')
      {
         $('#value').removeAttr("disabled");              
      }
      else{$('#value').prop('disabled', true);}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <label style="font-size:16px" for="comparator">Comparator:</label>
    <select id="comparator" name="comparator" onChange="changeTextBox();">
        <option value="lessthan">Less Than</option>
        <option value="lessthanequalto">Less Than or Equal To</option>
        <option value="greaterthan">Greater Than</option>
        <option value="greaterthanequalto">Greater Than or Equal To</option>
        <option value="equalto">Equal To</option>
        <option value="notequalto">Not Equal To</option>
        <option value="exists">Exists</option>
 </select>

<label style="font-size:16px" for="value">Value:</label>
<input type="number" id="value" disabled/>
</body>
</html>
```

CHEERSS :)