# Enable/Disable a txtBox according to comboBox value

Tags: javascript, html, combobox, getelementbyid, disabled-input

I ask you the following question I have to make sure that based on the choice of a value of the comboBox some textBox / some button are disabled .. looking on the forum I found this solution but it does not work ...

[Enable an HTML form text box based on the value of a drop down menu in the same form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17821081/enable-an-html-form-text-box-based-on-the-value-of-a-drop-down-menu-in-the-same)

I am attaching my code ...

```js
function changeTextBox() {
    comp = document.getElementById('tipologiaMezzoSubAffidataria');
    if(comp.value=='1 - Mezzi d opera')
        document.getElementById('documentiRadioComando').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('realizzazioneBasamento').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('rischioFulminazione').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('denunciaMessaInServizioInail').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('verificaPeriodicaInail').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('ultimaVerificaPeriodicaASL').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('scadenzaUltimaVerificaMezzoSubAffidataria').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('verificaTrimestraleFuni').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('scadenzaUltimaVerificaFuniMezzoSubAffidataria').disabled=true;
    else;
 if(comp.value=='2 - Automezzi')
  document.getElementById('certificatoConformitàCE').disabled=true;
        document.getElementById('registroPeriodicheInterne').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('documentiRadioComando').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('realizzazioneBasamento').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('correttaEsecuzioneBasamento').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('rischioFulminazione').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('denunciaMessaInServizioInail').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('verificaPeriodicaInail').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('ultimaVerificaPeriodicaASL').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('scadenzaUltimaVerificaMezzoSubAffidataria').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('verificaTrimestraleFuni').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('scadenzaUltimaVerificaFuniMezzoSubAffidataria').disabled=true;
    else;
 
  if(comp.value=='4 - Attrezzature')
        document.getElementById('annoCostruzioneMezzoSubAffidataria').disabled=true;
     document.getElementById('certificatoConformitàCE').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('librettoDiUsoEManutenzione').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('librettoDiCircolazione').disabled=true;
        document.getElementById('registroPeriodicheInterne').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('documentiRadioComando').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('realizzazioneBasamento').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('correttaEsecuzioneBasamento').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('rischioFulminazione').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('denunciaMessaInServizioInail').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('verificaPeriodicaInail').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('ultimaVerificaPeriodicaASL').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('scadenzaUltimaVerificaMezzoSubAffidataria').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('verificaTrimestraleFuni').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('scadenzaUltimaVerificaFuniMezzoSubAffidataria').disabled=true;
    else;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"  id="table4" name="table4"  class=" table order-list"> <tr>
       <form method="POST" action='azioniContinua/inserisciMezzoSubAffidatario.php'>

  <td  style="vertical-align: middle;" align="center" class="coloreTdAttiva">SI/NO</br><input  type="checkbox" class="chkView"/></td>
     <td bgcolor="#DCDCDC"><input type="text" name="idMezzoAttrezzaturaSubAffidataria" id="idMezzoAttrezzaturaSubAffidataria" width="75px" class="form-control chkEdit larghezzaBase" enable></td>
   <td width="144" bgcolor="#6DFD1E">AUTORIZZATO    /<br>NON AUTORIZZATO / <br> DOCUMENTI IN SCADENZA</td>
     <td>
   <select name="tipologiaMezzoSubAffidataria" id="tipologiaMezzoSubAffidataria" class="form-control chkEdit larghezzaBase" enable onChange="changeTextBox();">
     
   <option value="1 - Mezzi d opera">1 - Mezzi d opera</option>
   <option value="2 - Automezzi">2 - Automezzi</option>
   <option value="3 - Mezzi di sollevamento (All. VII del D-Lgs. 81/08)">3 - Mezzi di sollevamento (All. VII del D-Lgs. 81/08)</option>
   <option value="4 - Attrezzature">4 - Attrezzature</option>
   
      
     
   
 </select>
 </td>
     <td><input type="text" name="sottoTipologiaMezzoSubAffidataria" id="sottoTipologiaMezzoSubAffidataria" width="75px" class="form-control chkEdit larghezzaBase" enable></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="marcaMezzoSubAffidataria" id="marcaMezzoSubAffidataria" width="75px" class="form-control chkEdit larghezzaBase" enable></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="modelloMezzoSubAffidataria" id="modelloMezzoSubAffidataria" width="75px" class="form-control chkEdit larghezzaBase" enable></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="matricolaMezzoSubAffidataria" id="matricolaMezzoSubAffidataria" width="75px" class="form-control chkEdit larghezzaBase" enable></td>
     <td><input type="date" name="annoCostruzioneMezzoSubAffidataria" id="annoCostruzioneMezzoSubAffidataria" width="75px" class="form-control chkEdit larghezzaBase" enable></td>
     <td  class="coloreTdDrop" align="center">
  <div id="drop_file_zone" ondrop="upload_file(event)" style=" width: 100%; border: 1px dashed black;" ondragover="return false"> 
   <div id="drag_upload_file" >
    <p>CARICA FILE<p/>
    <input type="file" id="selectfile">
   </div>
  <input type="button" value="Seleziona File" id="certificatoConformitàCE" class="btn btn-success" onclick="file_explorer();">
  </div>
 </td><td  class="coloreTdDrop" align="center">
  <div id="drop_file_zone" ondrop="upload_file(event)" style=" width: 100%; border: 1px dashed black;" ondragover="return false"> 
   <div id="drag_upload_file" >
    <p>CARICA FILE<p/>
    <input type="file" id="selectfile">
   </div>
  <input type="button" value="Seleziona File" id="librettoDiUsoEManutenzione" class="btn btn-success" onclick="file_explorer();">
  </div>
 </td>
    <td  class="coloreTdDrop" align="center">
  <div id="drop_file_zone" ondrop="upload_file(event)" style=" width: 100%; border: 1px dashed black;" ondragover="return false"> 
   <div id="drag_upload_file" >
    <p>CARICA FILE<p/>
    <input type="file" id="selectfile">
   </div>
  <input type="button" value="Seleziona File" id="librettoDiCircolazione" class="btn btn-success" onclick="file_explorer();">
  </div>
 </td>
     <td  class="coloreTdDrop" align="center">
  <div id="drop_file_zone" ondrop="upload_file(event)" style=" width: 100%; border: 1px dashed black;" ondragover="return false"> 
   <div id="drag_upload_file" >
    <p>CARICA FILE<p/>
    <input type="file" id="selectfile">
   </div>
  <input type="button" value="Seleziona File" id="registroPeriodicheInterne" class="btn btn-success" onclick="file_explorer();">
  </div>
 </td>
    <td  class="coloreTdDrop" align="center">
  <div id="drop_file_zone" ondrop="upload_file(event)" style=" width: 100%; border: 1px dashed black;" ondragover="return false"> 
   <div id="drag_upload_file" >
    <p>CARICA FILE<p/>
    <input type="file" id="selectfile">
   </div>
  <input type="button" value="Seleziona File" id="documentiRadioComando" class="btn btn-success" onclick="file_explorer();">
  </div>
 </td>
    <td  class="coloreTdDrop" align="center">
  <div id="drop_file_zone" ondrop="upload_file(event)" style=" width: 100%; border: 1px dashed black;" ondragover="return false"> 
   <div id="drag_upload_file" >
    <p>CARICA FILE<p/>
    <input type="file" id="selectfile">
   </div>
  <input type="button" value="Seleziona File" id="realizzazioneBasamento" class="btn btn-success" onclick="file_explorer();">
  </div>
 </td>
     <td  class="coloreTdDrop" align="center">
  <div id="drop_file_zone" ondrop="upload_file(event)" style=" width: 100%; border: 1px dashed black;" ondragover="return false"> 
   <div id="drag_upload_file" >
    <p>CARICA FILE<p/>
    <input type="file" id="selectfile">
   </div>
  <input type="button" value="Seleziona File"  id="correttaEsecuzioneBasamento" class="btn btn-success" onclick="file_explorer();">
  </div>
 </td>
     <td  class="coloreTdDrop" align="center">
  <div id="drop_file_zone" ondrop="upload_file(event)" style=" width: 100%; border: 1px dashed black;" ondragover="return false"> 
   <div id="drag_upload_file" >
    <p>CARICA FILE<p/>
    <input type="file" id="selectfile">
   </div>
  <input type="button" value="Seleziona File" id="rischioFulminazione" class="btn btn-success" onclick="file_explorer();">
  </div>
 </td>
    <td  class="coloreTdDrop" align="center">
  <div id="drop_file_zone" ondrop="upload_file(event)" style=" width: 100%; border: 1px dashed black;" ondragover="return false"> 
   <div id="drag_upload_file" >
    <p>CARICA FILE<p/>
    <input type="file" id="selectfile">
   </div>
  <input type="button" value="Seleziona File"  id="denunciaMessaInServizioInail" class="btn btn-success" onclick="file_explorer();">
  </div>
 </td>
     <td  class="coloreTdDrop" align="center">
  <div id="drop_file_zone" ondrop="upload_file(event)" style=" width: 100%; border: 1px dashed black;" ondragover="return false"> 
   <div id="drag_upload_file" >
    <p>CARICA FILE<p/>
    <input type="file" id="selectfile">
   </div>
  <input type="button" value="Seleziona File" id="verificaPeriodicaInail" class="btn btn-success" onclick="file_explorer();">
  </div>
 </td>
     <td  class="coloreTdDrop" align="center">
  <div id="drop_file_zone" ondrop="upload_file(event)" style=" width: 100%; border: 1px dashed black;" ondragover="return false"> 
   <div id="drag_upload_file" >
    <p>CARICA FILE<p/>
    <input type="file" id="selectfile">
   </div>
  <input type="button" value="Seleziona File" id="ultimaVerificaPeriodicaASL"  class="btn btn-success" onclick="file_explorer();">
  </div>
 </td>
    <td><b>Scadenza:<b><br/><input type="date" name="scadenzaUltimaVerificaMezzoSubAffidataria" id="scadenzaUltimaVerificaMezzoSubAffidataria" width="75px" class="form-control chkEdit larghezzaBase" enable></td>
    <td  class="coloreTdDrop" align="center">
  <div id="drop_file_zone" ondrop="upload_file(event)" style=" width: 100%; border: 1px dashed black;" ondragover="return false"> 
   <div id="drag_upload_file" >
    <p>CARICA FILE<p/>
    <input type="file" id="selectfile">
   </div>
  <input type="button" value="Seleziona File" id="verificaTrimestraleFuni" class="btn btn-success" onclick="file_explorer();">
  </div>
 </td>
     <td><b>Scadenza:<b><br/><input type="date" name="scadenzaUltimaVerificaFuniMezzoSubAffidataria" id="scadenzaUltimaVerificaFuniMezzoSubAffidataria" width="75px" class="form-control chkEdit larghezzaBase" enable></td>
   <td><b>Note:<b><br/><input type="text" name="note" id="note" width="75px" class="form-control chkEdit larghezzaBase" enable></td>
          <td style=" border-style: none;"> <input type="text" name="fkIdAffidataria" id="fkIdAffidataria" width="75px" class="form-control chkEdit larghezzaBase" value="<?php echo $fkIdAffidataria?>"></td>

                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="location.href='subAffidatario.php'" value="Salva MezzoDiTrasporto" class="btn btn-primary"/></td>
     <td width="144" bgcolor="#6DFD1E">AUTORIZZATO    /<br>
       NON AUTORIZZATO</td>
     <td><input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="location.href='subAffidatario.php'" value="Scarica BADGE" class="btn btn-primary"/></td>
      <td>
   <select name="dataDiAutorizzazione" id="dataDiAutorizzazione" class="form-control chkEdit larghezzaBase" enable>
     
   <option value="Mezzi d'opera"></option>
   
   
   </select>
  </td>
</form>
      </tr>
      </table>
```

what I want to happen is that whenever I change the value of the comboBox the textboxes I put in the script are disabled.
For example the group ("1 - Mezzi d opera") must have deactivate the following fields:

```
 document.getElementById('documentiRadioComando').disabled=true;
    document.getElementById('realizzazioneBasamento').disabled=true;
    document.getElementById('rischioFulminazione').disabled=true;
    document.getElementById('denunciaMessaInServizioInail').disabled=true;
    document.getElementById('verificaPeriodicaInail').disabled=true;
    document.getElementById('ultimaVerificaPeriodicaASL').disabled=true;
    document.getElementById('scadenzaUltimaVerificaMezzoSubAffidataria').disabled=true;
    document.getElementById('verificaTrimestraleFuni').disabled=true;
    document.getElementById('scadenzaUltimaVerificaFuniMezzoSubAffidataria').disabled=true;
```

but everything else must be active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in addition to the problem related to the else, you also have the problem that every time you change you have to activate and deactivate all your fields .. otherwise they maintain the status of the previous choice

```js
if(comp.value=='1 - Mezzi d opera') {
  document.getElementById('sottoTipologiaMezzoSubAffidataria').disabled=false;
  document.getElementById('marcaMezzoSubAffidataria').disabled=false;
  document.getElementById('modelloMezzoSubAffidataria').disabled=false;
  document.getElementById('matricolaMezzoSubAffidataria').disabled=false;
  document.getElementById('annoCostruzioneMezzoSubAffidataria').disabled=false;
  document.getElementById('certificatoConformitàCE').disabled=false;
  document.getElementById('librettoDiUsoEManutenzione').disabled=false;
  document.getElementById('librettoDiCircolazione').disabled=false;
  document.getElementById('registroPeriodicheInterne').disabled=false;
  document.getElementById('documentiRadioComando').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('realizzazioneBasamento').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('correttaEsecuzioneBasamento').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('rischioFulminazione').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('denunciaMessaInServizioInail').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('verificaPeriodicaInail').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('ultimaVerificaPeriodicaASL').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('scadenzaUltimaVerificaMezzoSubAffidataria').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('verificaTrimestraleFuni').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('scadenzaUltimaVerificaFuniMezzoSubAffidataria').disabled=true;
} else if(comp.value=='2 - Automezzi') {
   document.getElementById('sottoTipologiaMezzoSubAffidataria').disabled=false;
  document.getElementById('marcaMezzoSubAffidataria').disabled=false;
  document.getElementById('modelloMezzoSubAffidataria').disabled=false;
  document.getElementById('matricolaMezzoSubAffidataria').disabled=false;
  document.getElementById('annoCostruzioneMezzoSubAffidataria').disabled=false;
  document.getElementById('certificatoConformitàCE').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('librettoDiUsoEManutenzione').disabled=false;
  document.getElementById('librettoDiCircolazione').disabled=false;
  document.getElementById('registroPeriodicheInterne').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('documentiRadioComando').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('realizzazioneBasamento').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('correttaEsecuzioneBasamento').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('rischioFulminazione').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('denunciaMessaInServizioInail').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('verificaPeriodicaInail').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('ultimaVerificaPeriodicaASL').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('scadenzaUltimaVerificaMezzoSubAffidataria').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('verificaTrimestraleFuni').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('scadenzaUltimaVerificaFuniMezzoSubAffidataria').disabled=true;
} else if(comp.value=='3 - Mezzi di sollevamento (All. VII del D-Lgs. 81/08)') {
  document.getElementById('sottoTipologiaMezzoSubAffidataria').disabled=false;
  document.getElementById('marcaMezzoSubAffidataria').disabled=false;
  document.getElementById('modelloMezzoSubAffidataria').disabled=false;
  document.getElementById('matricolaMezzoSubAffidataria').disabled=false;
  document.getElementById('annoCostruzioneMezzoSubAffidataria').disabled=false;
  document.getElementById('certificatoConformitàCE').disabled=false;
  document.getElementById('librettoDiUsoEManutenzione').disabled=false;
  document.getElementById('librettoDiCircolazione').disabled=false;
  document.getElementById('registroPeriodicheInterne').disabled=false;
  document.getElementById('documentiRadioComando').disabled=false;
  document.getElementById('realizzazioneBasamento').disabled=false;
  document.getElementById('correttaEsecuzioneBasamento').disabled=false;
  document.getElementById('rischioFulminazione').disabled=false;
  document.getElementById('denunciaMessaInServizioInail').disabled=false;
  document.getElementById('verificaPeriodicaInail').disabled=false;
  document.getElementById('ultimaVerificaPeriodicaASL').disabled=false;
  document.getElementById('scadenzaUltimaVerificaMezzoSubAffidataria').disabled=false;
  document.getElementById('verificaTrimestraleFuni').disabled=false;
  document.getElementById('scadenzaUltimaVerificaFuniMezzoSubAffidataria').disabled=false;
} else if (comp.value=='4 - Attrezzature'){
  document.getElementById('sottoTipologiaMezzoSubAffidataria').disabled=false;
  document.getElementById('marcaMezzoSubAffidataria').disabled=false;
  document.getElementById('modelloMezzoSubAffidataria').disabled=false;
  document.getElementById('matricolaMezzoSubAffidataria').disabled=false;
  document.getElementById('annoCostruzioneMezzoSubAffidataria').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('certificatoConformitàCE').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('librettoDiUsoEManutenzione').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('librettoDiCircolazione').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('registroPeriodicheInterne').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('documentiRadioComando').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('realizzazioneBasamento').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('correttaEsecuzioneBasamento').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('rischioFulminazione').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('denunciaMessaInServizioInail').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('verificaPeriodicaInail').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('ultimaVerificaPeriodicaASL').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('scadenzaUltimaVerificaMezzoSubAffidataria').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('verificaTrimestraleFuni').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('scadenzaUltimaVerificaFuniMezzoSubAffidataria').disabled=true;
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all your HTML is very messy, like missing close  tags or even using  instead 
 for break. The many attributes on the “table” element is obsolete...

You can use this tool to catch the syntax errors: 
https://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html

After that, you'll have to change your javascript structure, like said above.

```
function changeTextBox() {
comp = document.getElementById('tipologiaMezzoSubAffidataria');

if(comp.value=='1 - Mezzi d opera') {
  document.getElementById('documentiRadioComando').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('realizzazioneBasamento').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('rischioFulminazione').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('denunciaMessaInServizioInail').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('verificaPeriodicaInail').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('ultimaVerificaPeriodicaASL').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('scadenzaUltimaVerificaMezzoSubAffidataria').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('verificaTrimestraleFuni').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('scadenzaUltimaVerificaFuniMezzoSubAffidataria').disabled=true;
} else if(comp.value=='2 - Automezzi') {
  document.getElementById('certificatoConformitàCE').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('registroPeriodicheInterne').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('documentiRadioComando').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('realizzazioneBasamento').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('correttaEsecuzioneBasamento').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('rischioFulminazione').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('denunciaMessaInServizioInail').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('verificaPeriodicaInail').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('ultimaVerificaPeriodicaASL').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('scadenzaUltimaVerificaMezzoSubAffidataria').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('verificaTrimestraleFuni').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('scadenzaUltimaVerificaFuniMezzoSubAffidataria').disabled=true;
} else if (comp.value=='4 - Attrezzature'){
  document.getElementById('annoCostruzioneMezzoSubAffidataria').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('certificatoConformitàCE').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('librettoDiUsoEManutenzione').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('librettoDiCircolazione').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('registroPeriodicheInterne').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('documentiRadioComando').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('realizzazioneBasamento').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('correttaEsecuzioneBasamento').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('rischioFulminazione').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('denunciaMessaInServizioInail').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('verificaPeriodicaInail').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('ultimaVerificaPeriodicaASL').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('scadenzaUltimaVerificaMezzoSubAffidataria').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('verificaTrimestraleFuni').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('scadenzaUltimaVerificaFuniMezzoSubAffidataria').disabled=true;
}}
```

Comment: I'll give you the link to the validator .. I'll use it a lot more often

Comment: You also have to call the function on "change" event, so every time you change the value it runs.

Answer (score 0):

You have a strange "else" definition. Why do you put semicolon after your "else"?

> else;

Maybe it's the source of your problem?

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp